# Drawing arrows from one matrix node to others, with labels above them (Beamer)

Tags: beamer, arrows, overlays, tikz-matrix

I have a slide with a one-row matrix that I want appearing in the following way: the element in the middle appears first, with a box around it; then the element to its left and right appear simultaneously, with natural-looking arrows going from the center element to both of them, with some values written above or below the arrows (I'll choose above or below depending on how they look).

Currently, I have some of this code, but there are a few problems: 1) this entire row should be centered, it's not; 2) only one arrow shows up; 3) the text doesn't appear at the right place; 4) the arrows are too far down. I want them to be a bit closer to the row, it looks like there is a huge gap now.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,overlay-beamer-styles,tikzmark, matrix}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}         


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{title}

\begin{tcolorbox}[left = .8 mm, right=.8 mm]
Idea: here is the idea.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tikzpicture}[optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            thick,
            fill= white,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=5pt,
            align = center},
            row 1 column 2/.style={visible on = <2->}, 
            row 1 column 1/.style = {visible on = <3->}, 
            row 1 column 3/.style = {visible on =<3->}
            ]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=1em,
    nodes={anchor=west}
    ](M){
$f$ & |[alt=<2>{draw=green,thick,fill=white, rounded corners}{}]|$g$ & $r$\\
};  
    \draw[->, thick, visible on=<3->] (M-1-2)[out=-90,in=-90,loop,looseness=1] (M-1-1) node[midway, above] {$t=1$}; 
   \draw[->, thick, visible on=<3->] (M-1-2) to [out=-90,in=-90,loop,looseness=1] (M-1-3) node[midway, below] {$t=0$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{2em}

\onslide<4->{ 
If the following inequality holds: \[a \leq b,\] then combine with result 1 + result 2 + result 3 to finish the proof.}

\vspace{2em}
\onslide<5->{
However, this is {\color{red}FALSE}; counter-example:
\[1 + 1 = 2.\]}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your problems:

1. You can use `\hfill` to center the `tikzpicture`.
2. You forgot a `to`, should not use `loop` for an arrow going from A to B, and if you wish to place a node along a curved path, you need to put it *before* the target.<sup>1</sup>
3. To get the frame only on a certain overlay, you can use

   `|[draw=green,thick,fill=white, rounded
   corners,alt=<2>{opacity=1}{opacity=0,text opacity=1}]|`

I also added some annotations to the code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,overlay-beamer-styles,tikzmark, matrix}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}         


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{title}

\begin{tcolorbox}[left = .8 mm, right=.8 mm]
Idea: here is the idea.
\end{tcolorbox}

\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            thick,
            fill= white,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=5pt,
            align = center},
            row 1 column 2/.style={visible on = <2->}, 
            row 1 column 1/.style = {visible on = <3->}, 
            row 1 column 3/.style = {visible on =<3->}
            ]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=1em,
    nodes={anchor=west}
    ](M){
$f$ & |[draw=green,thick,fill=white, rounded
corners,alt=<2>{opacity=1}{opacity=0,text opacity=1}]|$g$ & $r$\\
};  
    \draw[->, thick, visible on=<3->] 
    (M-1-2) to[out=90,in=90,looseness=1] node[midway, above] {$t=1$}
    (M-1-1) ;  % target node needs to be last, no loop & you forgot "to"
   \draw[->, thick, visible on=<3->] (M-1-2) to [out=-90,in=-90,looseness=1]
     node[midway, below] {$t=0$} (M-1-3);  % target node needs to be last, no loop
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill\mbox{}\par
\vspace{2em}

\onslide<4->{ 
If the following inequality holds: \[a \leq b,\] then combine with result 1 + result 2 + result 3 to finish the proof.}

\vspace{2em}
\onslide<5->{
However, this is \textcolor{red}{FALSE}; counter-example:
\[1 + 1 = 2.\]}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub><sup>1</sup>Ti*k*Z is very forgiving for straight paths, where you can put `node[pos=0.5]{...}` *after* the target. I somethimes think it would have been easier if you always need to put it before....</sub>

Comment: As always, fantastic answer. Thanks especially for pointing out what I did incorrect. I'll (hopefully) not forget these errors!